# pyspark json read ignores empty set

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

In Pyspark, whenever i read a json file with an empty set element. The entire element is ignored in the resultant DataFrame. How can i ask spark to consider without ignoring it.

I am using spark 2.4.2 and Python 3.7.3

I tried using df.fillna('Null'). This didnt work because the moment DataFrame got created, the element is not there.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SimpleApp").getOrCreate()

people = ['{"name":{},"address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}']
otherPeopleRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(people)
otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD)

otherPeople.printSchema()

root
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

As we can see, the empty set element (name) is not part of Dataframe.
Is there a way to have name element to be considered.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Let me know if that helps:**

```
people = ['{"name":{},"address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}']
otherPeopleRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(people)
otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD)


#  lit with None
otherPeople = otherPeople.withColumn('name', lit(None).cast(StringType()))

otherPeople.printSchema()

root
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

+---------------+----+
|        address|name|
+---------------+----+
|[Columbus,Ohio]|null|
+---------------+----+
```

> **EDIT**

if the json is not too complex this will work.

```
#  Change the dictionary itself than changing it at df level
import json
d = json.loads(people[0])


#  Takes care of any column which has empty dictionary value
for k, v in d.items():
    if ( (v is None)  | (len(v) == 0) ):   # You can add any conditions to detect empty set
        d[k] = "nan"  # i prefer d[k] = None, and then fillna


people[0] = str(json.dumps(d))


otherPeopleRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(people)
otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD)
otherPeople.printSchema()
otherPeople.show()

root
     |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
     |-- name: string (nullable = true)

    +---------------+----+
    |        address|name|
    +---------------+----+
    |[Columbus,Ohio]|nan |
    +---------------+----+
```

Comment: Preetham, the above suggestion works after you have read Dataframe, but in my case we need to know while reading json. Because i have huge json file and we dont know which element has empty set that would get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of hours struggling with a similar problem, here is what I found:

If data has at least one row with a nonempty "name" field, then it won't be ignored. If it doesn't, then we need to add "name" column with init value like [@Preetham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6222977/preetham) said. so we can check if "name" exists in the result's schema or not.

Another solution would be adding a sample row with all fields filled with data to the json file/string and then ignoring or removing it from the result.